# Could any one please point out the mistake in the IF statement

Tags: java

I am very new to JAVA and couldn'y figure out the problem with the IF statement

```
class SpaceRemover {

    public static void main() {

        String mostFamous= "This is a test";
        char[] mfl = mostFamous.toCharArray();

        for (int dex = 0; dex < mfl.length; dex++) {
            char current = mfl[dex];    

            if (current != "") {
                System.out.print(current);
            } else {
                System.out.print(".");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW `public static void main (String [] args)` should be

Comment: Search for "java compare string" (on SO) for many duplicates and a few interesting quirks. That being said, **make sure to say what the error is** (e.g. include the error message, stack-trace, unexpected behavior). In this case it is a type error and won't even compile (and even if it compile it still wouldn't work as expected). Remember: we don't see your screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the class name and code provided, I assume you are trying to remove all spaces from a string and replacing them with periods?

Your issue lies in the line

```
if (current != "") {
```

Firstly, that's not a space, that's an empty string.
Secondly, you should compare it to a char.

It should be like this:

```
if (current != ' ') {
```

Answer (score 2):

`current` is defined as a `char` but you're trying to compare it to a `String`. Quite simply, that is an error in your code, and the Java compiler will have informed you of such with an [error message](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=incomparable+types%3a+char+and+java.lang.String&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) to the effect of

> `incomparable types: char and java.lang.String`

The error message is saying that you can not compare a `char` to a `String`. Learn to read these error messages, it will pay immense dividends for you in the future.

Right now you have the empty `String`, there is no corresponding value for `char` but it appears that you meant to compare to space "`' '`" anyway. Thus:

```
if (current != ' ') {
    System.out.print(current);
}
else {
    System.out.print(".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should compare characters with `current.equals(' ')` method

and you are comparing character with a string here